# android notifications fail to sort completely by lexicographical order when grouping with sortkey

Tags: android, sorting, push-notification, grouping, lexicographic

I am testing sorting android notifications by using [grouping](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/group#group-notification) and [sortKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setSortKey(java.lang.String)), the order android shown in the tray **seems incorrect** to me according to **lexicographical order.**

Referring to android official doc about [sortKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setSortKey(java.lang.String))

> Notifications will be sorted lexicographically using this value

In my test, I posted 6 notifications w/ same channel = "channelId", groupId = "group_id_2", and various sortKeys = ["1", "10", "11", "111", "2", "3"], posting at the same time.

The result I am expecting is [1, 10, 11, 111, 2, 3], according to lexicographical oder. But the tray shows [10, 111, 11, 1, 2, 3], [screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD1c3.png). Is it correct based on lexicographical order?

The code is as below, [tray screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD1c3.png)

```
package com.example.tray;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id_";
    private final static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_2 = NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID + "2";
    private final static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "channel_name_";
    private final static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_2 = NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME + "2";
    private final static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION =
            "channel description";
    private final static String NOTIFICATION_GROUP_ID_2 = "group_id_" + "2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupNotificationChannelAndSentPush();
    }

    private void setupNotificationChannelAndSentPush() {
        //Create channel 2
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel2 = createPushChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_2,
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_2);
        NotificationManager nm = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        nm.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel2);

        //Post 6 push to Channel_2, Group_2
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            int notificationId = i;

            @Nullable String sortKey = null;
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    sortKey = "1";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    sortKey = "10";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sortKey = "11";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sortKey = "111";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sortKey = "2";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    sortKey = "3";
                    break;

            }
            Notification notification =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_2)
                            .setGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP_ID_2)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                            .setSortKey(sortKey)
                            .setContentTitle("Notification Title " + i)
                            .setContentText(getContent(notificationId,
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_2, NOTIFICATION_GROUP_ID_2, sortKey))
                            .build();

            // if notificationId is the same, then that means replace existing one
            nm.notify(notificationId, notification);

            sleep();
        }
    }

    // Create push channel, priority = default
    private NotificationChannel createPushChannel(String notificationChannelId,
                                                  String notificationChannelName) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel =
                new NotificationChannel(notificationChannelId, notificationChannelName,
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        return notificationChannel;
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    private String getContent(int notificationId, String channelId, String groupId, String sortKey) {
        return String.format("notifId:%d, channelId:%s, groupId:%s, sortKey:%s", notificationId,
                channelId, groupId, sortKey);
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping beforehand!